# How to get an Object property from an ArrayList of Objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having some trouble trying to retrive a property from an ArrrayList in other Object...
This is the idea:

I have a class Guest with a String "name" property:

```
Guest guest01 = new Guest("Andrew"); 
Guest guest02 = new Guset("john");
ArrayList<Guest> list = new ArrayList();
```

And I have a class Booking with an ArrayList of Guests property:

```
Booking booking = new Booking(list);
```

now I want to retrieve each name so i've tryed:

```
for(Guest guest : booking.getList())
{
    System.out.println(guest.getName()); 

}
```

and also tryed:

```
Iterator it=booking.getList().iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){

    Object objet = it.next();
        Guest g = (Guest)objeto;
        System.out.println(g.getDNI());

    }
```

In both cases I get an:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Booking booking= new Booking();

Comment: Where do you exactly get the Exception? Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: It would be nice to see the Booking class you pass the list, make sure that on booking.getList() returns what you pass... (this.list = list in constructor)

Comment: Note: don't use raw types. Use `new ArrayList<>()` - note the `<>` before the parentheses.

Comment: we can't possibly help you, as we have no idea where to look, the issue can be anywhere, full classes & stacktraces will help

Comment: can you provide more information on your exception ? Parts of the code also will help. This exception seems to be associated with the awt/swing components of your projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume Booking.getList() is returning null. Did you use 'this' in the constructor in order to assign the list to the field?

```
public class Booking {
  private List<Guest> list;

  public Booking(List<Guest> list) {
    this.list = list; // Using of this
  } 

  public List<Guest> getList() {
    return list;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I forgot to inicialize in the constructor!!

Answer (score 0):

Can we see what happening in Booking class?
Better way to create object is, create property with validation.

Worse practice is this :

```
Booking booking = new Booking(list);
```

Good practice is :

```
Booking booking = new Booking();

booking.add(list); //in add method you should have validation,like instanceOf ...
```

Try to debug your code,and share with us result.